# Angular JS Evaluation difference for wrong Controller name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and was studying through tutorial and then found something weird.

Let us assume in a JS file i have defined a controller as

```
   //Create the module
      var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

    // Creating the controller and registering with the module all done in one line.
      myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.message = "AngularJS Tutorial";
      });
```

Now i have created a html page where i use this controller

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
   <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
   <div>
      {{ message }}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This returns me Output as

```
 AngularJS Tutorial
```

Now when i wrongly type the name of controller

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
   <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
   <div ng-controller="myController1">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case it gives

```
 AngularJS Tutorial
{{ message }}
```

Now though the myContoller1 does not exists and i get a error also but still 
{{message}} not exists in 1st try(1st method where no controller defined in div)  and should have been printed same as it is.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Scope of controller will only applicable within a DOM on which it applied.

In first case you didn't see `{{message}}` value in second `div` because you had that binding outside `myController` div. It would have work if you have wrapped bindings in `myController` div.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <div>
      {{ message }}
   </div>
   <div ng-controller="myController1">
      {{ message }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Where as in 2nd case you don't have `myController1`, so angular failed while creating instance of `myController1` controller(tip: check console for error, if something doesn't work in JS).